# Manage user profiles with Wordpress

Tags: users, profiles

I would like to create a website for a scholarship. For that, I want to create three pages for seeing all members of the scholarship:

- one for members of the board of trustees (people who created it)
- one for current scholars
- one for former scholars

I am new to Wordpress and this is my first serious project with it. My question is: What is the best way to handle this data. To specify my needs furter, I will describe the data a little bit more.

A record that represents a member of the board of trustees should contain the name, one image and a short text (maybe an email address later on).

A record that represents a scholar should contain the information about whether this scholar is a former or a current member. my aim is to sort the records according to this information (the site for the alumni should contain all former members). Furthermore, it should say in which class the scholar is. This should be sortable as well. The other entries should contain text or an unordered list.

I don't want a complete project or tons of sample code. I would like to get to know whether anybody has experience with a similar problem and maybe with a plugin I could use. I found many plugins that deal with user issues and therefore I want to ask for experience with one plugin or maybe some recommendations.

Update #1:

I already built this application using Django. The project with Wordpress should be a cleaner rebuilt with a better admin interface. The following links show how my desired output looks like (it is in German but the concept should be clear):

- [Alumni](http://www.mathias-kleyboldt-stiftung.de/alumni)
- [current scholar](http://www.mathias-kleyboldt-stiftung.de/stipendiaten/portraets)

Comment: Unfortunately your question is just too broad and falls into the scope of do-my-work-for-me. What you are asking is for a complete project. I would suggest that you hire someone to accomplish this if you are not comfortable working on this by yourself. You should break your question down, and tackle each question on its own and then come back if you fail with what ever you have and explain where you are lacking

Comment: What have you done so far? What research have you completed or code have you written?

Comment: Sorry if my question was too broad. I don't want that anybody does the work for me. Therefore, I updated my question to specify it. I wanted to ask for experience with a plugin and to get a recommendation (maybe with some short lines of sample code for the sake of demonstration)

Comment: How are you going to input data for these user types?

Comment: Just a note, product recommendations are of topic. Please visit [ask] to learn how to ask a good question :-)

Comment: @Gangesh I hoped that there is a plugin out there that adds functionality for this, maybe in form of a separate area in the Wordpress admin.

Comment: I added links to the current site that I want to rebuild. They show the output I try to get.

Comment: @NickLehmann You won't get exactly what you want with Just adding a plugin. If all data is entered from admin then you can easily create Custom Post Types for User types with required Custom fields. You can start from there.
Or hire a developer. :)

Comment: @Gangesh I have already programmed a blog on this site. So you suppose that I create one post for each scholar and create a custom format for them, right? Or that I write my own plugin.

Comment: @NickLehmann You need to create Custom post types for these user type just to keep your blog post separate, also you will need different custom fields for each post type. Alot of plugins are available for both these tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are going to enter all data by yourself you can make use of Custom Post Types.

Create 3 CPTs for each user type, Trustee, Alumni, Scholar. And with that create custom fields as per your need for each CPT.

Once all data is in, then you need is to create Custom Page templates for each post type where you can list users in your design format.

You can easily find plugins for creating CPT and Custom fields quickly.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can create different user roles with [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/). And you can get users by role with:

```
$my_custom_users = get_users('role=your_role_is_here');
```

This function return array of user search results. Use this with foreach in your custom page template:

```
foreach ($my_custom_users as $user){
        print_r($user);
}
```

*For create custom page templates;*
Create a php file. Add this comment line to first line:

```
/*
Template Name: Your Custom Template
*/
```

Now, you can create new page in wp-admin/pages. This page include to above get and foreach codes.